# Arch linuxBoot hangs on Started Update man-db cache

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, startup, pacman

After a full upgrade of the system with `pacman -Syu`

The kernel has been updated, but when I shut down the laptop and open it again it hangs on this message:

```
[   OK   ] Reached target Graphical Interfaces 

[   OK   ] Started Rotate log files 

[   OK   ] Stopped LXDE Display Manager.

[   OK   ] Started LXDE Display Manager.

[   OK   ] Stopped LXDE Display Manager.

[   OK   ] Started LXDE Display Manager.

[   OK   ] Started Update man-db cache.
```

Comment: Have you checked `var/log/pacman.log` for anything that might be out of order?

Comment: Nope I have reinstalled the kernel and reinstalled the AMD Display driver but after that it only stops at >[   OK   ] Reached target Graphical Interfaces 
With a failed to load kernel modules message